# Java clientSocket stuck at reading

Tags: java, sockets

```
               byte[] buffer = new byte[128 * 1024];
               int bytesRead = 0;
               while(bytesRead < 128 * 1024){
                    int result = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer, bytesRead, 128 * 1024 - bytesRead);
                    bytesRead+=result;
                }
```

I'm reading a 5Mb file from socket and I'm trying to fill a 128kb buffer but it gets stuck on the last read where it reads less than 128kb for example 19kb since that's last chunk of bytes. How do I break this loop on the last read? The other problem is it doesn't return -1 when it reaches the last read. It just gets stuck there.

Comment: What you should do is just read until end of stream: `while ((result = in.read(buffer)) > 0) { ... }`. You won't get -1 untill the peer closes his socket, which evidently isn't happening. But you don't need to keep reading into the same buffer. Dispose of the data as you receive it. It's quicker and saves memory.

Comment: The problem with the logic is when the stream runs out of data the `read` returns -1 (for no more) the resultant `bytesRead` goes **down** not up and will keep going down for-ever  (well until you've wrapped around the 32bit down to zero, all negative numbers, then when `bytesRead == MAX_INT` it stops.

Comment: @user207421 the problem is it only reads 512 bytes each read and it slows the transfer so I reduce the number of writes by filling a big buffer.

Comment: For a file the above was correct, for a socket *unless* the other end closes the socket the assumption should be there will still be data (it just might be a while till you get it - i.e. timeouts).